# Windows Server 2003 64bit IIS 6.0 Service Unavailable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.0, asp.net-web-api, iis-6, windows-server-2003-r2

I created a MVC 4 Web Api and ran all the configurations to get it running, but I get the error mentioned above.

The event log says I am running two version of .NET

I have enabled 32 bit applications on the server

This is the proof of .NET 4 Registration:

[image: CMD]

This is the error I am getting:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Event viewer]

The setup for above error:

[image: Website Properties]

Clicking on configure from above screen:

[image: Application Configuration]

Clicking on edit:

[image: When choosing version 4 isapi]

If I change the wildcard mapping dll to the follwing

[image: When choosing version 2 isapi]

I get this error, as you can see it says I am running version 2 of .net which is not true according to the first screenshot, I have tried iisreset to not avail:

[image: Error2]

The wild card mappings are used for clean url's when using MVC 4 web api.

This is the setup in IIS:

[image: IIS]

Can someone maybe guide me to a solution for this?

**EDIT:**

These are the resources for the initial setup I did:

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx

http://johan.driessen.se/posts/getting-an-asp.net-4-application-to-work-on-iis6

Basically the IIS has framework 4 registered but it is using framework 2 when I try and load the api.